# Using Variables - Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

When I run the program, the first step is to add a number and another etc. whenever I input `m` or `l` (the variables I created) an error pops up, however it works fine when I just use numbers. How do i make my variables usable to input. (Apologies if I'm not making sense, its hard to explain)

```
package pizza;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class size {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double m, l;    
        m = 4;
        l = 5;

        Scanner pizzasize = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fstep, sstep, tstep, ostep, lstep, tot;  
        m = 4;
        l = 5;
        System.out.println("Enter pizza size:");
        fstep = pizzasize.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter pizza size:");
        sstep = pizzasize.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter pizza size:");
        tstep = pizzasize.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter pizza size:");
        ostep = pizzasize.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter pizza size:");
        lstep = pizzasize.nextDouble();
        tot = fstep+sstep+tstep+ostep+lstep;
        System.out.println(tot);

        pizzasize.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: _whenever i input `m`or `l` (the variables i created) an error pops up._ of course it will because the scanner is expecting a number to be entered.

Comment: Works fine! You mean inserting string instead of number -_-

Comment: What are you actually expecting when `m` or `l` are entered?

Answer (score 2):

As @Ousmane Mahy Diaw noted, `nextDouble()` is going to take a number, not a string such as "m" or "l".  If you want it to accept either a string or a double, you have to modify your code to check the `Scanner` input.

```
m = 4;
l = 5;
System.out.println("Enter pizza size:");
if(pizzasize.hasNextDouble()){
    fstep = pizzasize.nextDouble();
}else{
    String input = pizzasize.next();
    if(input.equals("m")){
        fstep = m;
    }
    else if(input.equals("l")){
        fstep = l;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont really know much about java to be honest. What do you mean by check the scanner input?